# Tool to export figures only to individual pdfs

Tags: mactex, mac, texpad

I have a really big report that I have been writing in latex. The report has a number of figures that have been included using either `\includegraphics` or `Tikz` drawings. The files that i include are either PDF, PNG, eps or JPEG files.

I have got a request to send the report to someone as a word document with figures sent as separate pdf files. I have managed to convert the pdf-report to word. I have also found that by using something like the following latex code, I can create each jpg/png image´s pdf (one by one).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %support for eps.
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.ps,.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{float} % figure placing [H]
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\minipage{1.08\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/a_jpg_figure.jpg}
\end{figure}
\endminipage

\end{document}
```

However, this takes a very long time and I haven't got that much time. So i wonder whether there is a tool that can be used to "compile" the latex file much like pdflatex but instead output only the "standalone" figures in the resulting pdf file (s) without (much) editing of my original latex file.

I am using Texpad with macTex on a mac :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`preview`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview) package.

Loading it with the options `active,graphics,tightpage` will produce a `.pdf` file where each page is one image.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[active,graphics,tightpage]{preview}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{B figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{C figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Then you can use a tool to extract each page as a separate file.

If you want to extract your `tikzpicture`s also, add in the preamble

```
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: is that an extra square bracket after `\PreviewEnvironment`?

Comment: `\PreviewEnvironment` works when placed after `begin{document}` but not in the preamble. In addition twhen you have a figure environment with more than two-includes, each sub figure goes to its page.

Comment: @jjunju `\PreviewEnvironment` works in the preamble if put after loading `preview`. In regards of multiple `\includegraphics` you can try substituting the `graphics` option with `floats` so the whole contents of the `figure` environment goes on the same page.